# Math inequality problem - finding the number of positions for x

Tags: inequality

I came across [this](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/124/A) question here while practising for an upcoming competition.

The problem is as follows:

Petr stands in the line of `n` people, but he doesn't know exactly which position he occupies. He can say that there are no less than `a` people standing in front of him and no more than `b` people standing behind him. Find the number of different positions Petr can occupy.

**Input**

The only line contains three integers `n`, `a` and `b` $(0 ≤ a, b < n ≤ 100)$.

**Output**

Print the single number — the number of the sought positions.

**Examples**

input

`3 1 1`

output

`2`

input

`5 2 3`

output

`3`

And the editorial explanation is as follows:

Let's iterate through each item and check whether it is appropriate to the conditions $a ≤ i - 1$ and $n - i ≤ b$ (for `i` from `1` to `n`). The first condition can be converted into $a + 1 ≤ i$, and the condition $n - i ≤ b$ in $n - b ≤ i$, then the general condition can be written $max(a + 1, n - b) ≤ i$ and then our answer can be calculated by the formula $n - max(a + 1, n - b) + 1$.

Unfortunately, going through the editorial, I am not able to get an intuitive understanding of how the mathematical expression $n - max(a + 1, n - b) + 1$ was arrived.

Could someone please give an intuitive explanation of the solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know there are at least $a$ positions before Petr and at most $b$ positions after Petr.

Let $i$ be a possible position for Petr. Then $1,2,...,i-1$ are the positions in front of Petr and this number, $i-1$, must be at least $a$, i.e. $i-1\ge a\implies i\ge a+1$ which is equivalent to $a+1\le i$.

The positions after Petr are $i+1, i+2, ..., n$ and the number of these is $n-i$ which must be at most $b$. Therefore, $n-i\le b\implies n-b\le i$.

Since both $a+1$ and $n-b$ are less than or equal to $i$, the maximum of the two is less than or equal to $i$. We take this number $m=\text{max}(a+1,n-b)$ to be the minimum position that Petr can occupy.

Now Petr can occupy positions $m,m+1,...,n$ and the number of these is $n-(m-1)=n-m+1$ which is the formula you asked about.

Comment: but I am confused with the problem statement `a people standing in front of him`, so don't you think, based on this statement it should have been $i <= n-a$ instead of $n-b <= i$ ? because by problem statement `b people standing behind him`. So if `1 2 3 4 ... i i+i i+2 i+3 ... n`, then if I am looking from right to left, then it should have been $i-1 <= b$ implies $i <= b+1$?

Comment: @UtkalSinha I am viewing the front of the line as position $1$. If you wish to view the back of the line as position $1$ the problem will still work. I am following the convention of the person who wrote the solution.

Comment: thanks, makes sense.